# issue with SublimeText2 configuration and "ruby_eval" installation

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I got a good link [`jugyo / SublimeRubyEval`](https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval) to run the code in the editor itself like `IRB`. I have installed "RubyEval" using the ST2 package manger.

In my Preferences.sublime-settings, I put:

```
"ruby_eval": {
    // "ruby": "/usr/local/bin/ruby"
    "ruby": "~/.rvm/bin/ruby"
  }
```

Now when I tried to run the code using `super+k`, nothing happened. Any one help me for the same?

I am on ***Ubuntu13.04***

Comment: did you use short key: super + k, e ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not work for me neither.

sublime version is 2.0.2

check console find out (ctrl + `):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
File "./RubyEval.py", line 69, in run
File "./RubyEval.py", line 50, in eval_as_ruby
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

If you have same problem check https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval/pull/8

I fixed it. works for me.

BTW: Use [jugyo / SublimeRubyEval](https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval) is easiest way to genrate some text (like repeat html) in the sublime edit view. Other things like SublimeREPL those are too heavy to do that.

Comment: I became Vim user... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) instead. It uses [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) instead of `IRB`, but it has a ton of features, support for many languages, is actively under development, has a large userbase, and most importantly a responsive main developer. It's available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) and is one of my favorite ST2 plugins. You can't go wrong with it!

And no, I'm not the dev...

Comment: no I want the code output,in the editor where I am writing the code!

Comment: SublimeREPL does this. There are commands for evaluating the current selection, file, line, or block in the running REPL, and also for directly transferring the current selection, file, line, or block to the REPL so you can play with it further. The REPL runs as just another tab in ST2, so you can easily switch back and forth.

Comment: from package control I just installed it, now how to run the code.

Comment: I am getting error `OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')`.

Comment: Hit `ctrl-shift-p` to open the Command Palette, then type "`pci`" to get "Package Control: Install Package". Hit enter, then just type "`sublimerepl`" and hit enter again, and it should install. After it's installed I'd restart, then go to `Tools->SublimeREPL->Ruby->Ruby` and you should be all set. If `~/.rvm/bin/ruby` is **not** before the system `ruby` command in your `$PATH` and the wrong version starts up, just let me know and I'll edit my answer to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: please re edit your post with all the technical settings we discussed in our chat.